# How can use the AnyObject.filter method?

Tags: swift, filter, anyobject

I tried to use the AnyObject.filter method, however the following error is returned:

> Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored.

This is my code:

```
func listCaptureDevices(type: String?) -> [AnyObject]!
{

    // Initialize capture session
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    // List all capture devices
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    if type == nil
    {
        return devices
    }


    // Filter by device type
    return devices.filter() {
        if (device.hasMediaType(type == "audio" ? AVMediaTypeAudio : AVMediaTypeVideo))
        {
            return true
        }
    }

}
```

I observed that AnyObject accepts a predicated as parameter, however in the Swift examples I observed that is possible to use a closure (Examples with array of integers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `AnyObject` doesn't have a `filter` method. That method is on `SequenceType`.

There are a lot of problems in your code; we'll walk through them.

```
return devices.filter() {
```

While this technically works, you don't want the `()` here. It just creates confusion. You mean this:

```
return devices.filter {
```

Your next problem is that you refer to `device` which you didn't declare. You probably meant to add `device in` to your closure. Alternately, you can refer to the element as `$0`.

Finally, your closure doesn't return anything in the false case. You always have to return something.

You can simplify all of this to:

```
return devices.filter { 
    $0.hasMediaType(type == "audio" ? AVMediaTypeAudio : AVMediaTypeVideo)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand how the filter and sort methods work with Swift. You example work like a charm and it is quite simple (just one line).

Answer (score 1):

```
return devices.filter() {device in
    if (device.hasMediaType(type == "audio" ? AVMediaTypeAudio : AVMediaTypeVideo))
    {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is good to have an alternative solution. I can see that device works like a array element into the scope. Thanks to your solution and the first one I have a good undersanding about how the filter method works with Swift.